# Select query for a login

Tags: query, select

I'm trying to make a login form, but select query isn't working. Is there another syntax in WordPress and in which way is password hashed?
My code is:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    if ( !$_POST['username']  ) {
        echo "You did not complete all of the required fields";
    } else { 
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $query = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_users
            WHERE user_login='@admin' && user_pass = 'some_pass'" );
        if ( $query != null ) {
            echo "Login success";
            return true;
        } else {
            echo "incorrect pass or user";
            return false;
        }
    }
} 
?>
<form action="" method="post"/>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/> 
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"/><br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [wp_signon](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) function

Here is an example

```
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = 'example';
    $creds['user_password'] = 'plaintextpw';
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
        echo $user->get_error_message();
```

Comment: It gives me error: The password field is empty. I used: $username=$_POST['username'];
   $password=$_POST['password'];
$creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] =$username ;
    $creds['user_pass'] = $password;
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
        echo $user->get_error_message();   <form action="" method="post"/>
 <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/> 
 <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"/><br> 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Answer (score 1):

you need to just put it in to variable and that variable call in to query.

```
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "sign_up";
        $query = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $table_name
            WHERE email_id='".$username."' && password = '".$password."'" );
```